# XSLT how to check if element exist in array

Tags: xslt

XML:

```
<Calendars xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Urnik.xsd">
    <Calendar>
        <Name>Marko</Name>
        <Days>
            <Day>
                <Date>2013-05-13</Date>
                <DayType>1</DayType>
                <DayWorking>1</DayWorking>
                <WorkingTimes>
                    <WorkingTime>
                        <FromTime>08:00</FromTime>
                        <ToTime>11:00</ToTime>
                        <Name>Izpit Matematika</Name>
                        <Owner>Marko</Owner>
                        <Category>
                            <School Professor="111" Room="1" Subject="882" />
                        </Category>
                    </WorkingTime>
                    <WorkingTime>
                        <FromTime>13:00</FromTime>
                        <ToTime>17:00</ToTime>
                        <Name>Vaje APZ</Name>
                        <Owner>Marko</Owner>
                        <Category>
                            <School Professor="222" Room="11" Subject="881"/>
                        </Category>
                    </WorkingTime>      
                    <WorkingTime>
                        <FromTime>20:00</FromTime>
                        <ToTime>22:00</ToTime>
                        <Name>Vaje aaaaaa</Name>
                        <Owner>Marko</Owner>
                        <Category>
                            <School Professor="222" Room="11" Subject="881"/>
                        </Category>
                    </WorkingTime>                      
                </WorkingTimes>
            </Day>
            <Day>
                <Date>2013-05-14</Date>
                <DayType>2</DayType>
                ...
            </Day>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Calendar/Days/Day">   
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="DayType = 1">
            <xsl:variable name="vTransfers" select="child::*/WorkingTime"/>
```

Can I somehow check this variable `vTransfers` if `08:00` exist in `FromTime`. I do not want to loop it beacuse I need to place it in correct `TD` row. And I am now in this TD and i woul like to check if `08:00` exist in `FromTime` in this array.

I try something like

```
<xsl:when test="contains($vTransfers/ToTime, '08:00')">
                        <xsl:text>IN</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>                                     
                        <xsl:text>OUT</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
```

but always takes just firs one and not check whole array.

Comment: You always must include the output HTML you want to see. (Also - since you've deleted your previous question: Did you manage to solve it yourself?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a node-set to `contains`, it is converted to a string. This means that only string value of the first node is taken. Try something like that:

```
<xsl:when test="$vTransfers[contains(ToTime, '08:00')]">
```

This should work, too:

```
<xsl:when test="WorkingTimes/WorkingTime/ToTime = '08:00'">
```

Comment: Easier: `<xsl:when test="$vTransfers[ToTime = '08:00']">` - `contains()` is redundant here.